# how to prevent all <a> navigation when a button inside it is clicked? example: <a href="url1"><a href="url2"><button>click</button></a></a>

Tags: javascript

I have a constraint in my actual code, but this question may help me with my problem, it is similar to this.

I know it's a bad idea to have 2 embedded anchor tags, but it's a restriction of a code that I can't change in a real project, but I'm excited to learn some way to have a solution to the problem I present

I have an `anchor tag` that is a parent of another `anchor tag`, and this last `anchor tag` has a `button`. I want that when I click exclusively on this button, prevent the execution of the navigation of the `anchor tag` and execute the function of the button.

but I want the navigation to proceed normally if you click on any other element than the `button`.

How can I do it?

```js
function clickedButton(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 console.log("click");
 alert("click")
}
```

```css
body,html{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

#mainLink{
  border:1px solid red;
}

#secondaryLink{
  border:1px solid blue;
 padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" id="mainLink">
   go to google
    <a href="www.wikipedia.com" id="secondaryLink">
        go to wikipedia
        <button onclick="clickedButton(event)">click</button>
    </a>
</a>
```

Comment: That HTML is invalid. You can not have anchors and buttons nested.

Comment: _Why_ do you have nested anchors? That seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: @epascarello why is invalid?

Comment: @yavgz, you mentioned in your other question that a button in an anchor was for accessibility. Invalid HTML isn't good for accessibility, and this is even worse than the one from the other question. Are you sure you are understanding the accessibility requirements that you are working towards?

Comment: @imvain2 Yes, I understood that the problem is because one solution is to prevent the navigation of all anchor tags.

Comment: @Andy I know it's a bad idea to have 2 embedded anchor tags, but it's a restriction of a code that I can't change in a real project, but I'm excited to learn some way to have a solution to the problem I present

Comment: *"Transparent, except that no descendant may be interactive content or an a element, and no descendant may have a specified tabindex attribute."* [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#properties)

Comment: The browser renders it as `<a>go to google</a><a>....</a>` so it is trying to fix the bad HTML. Who knows what every engine does when it encounters this nested code.

Comment: Someone then, not you, needs to change that code.

Comment: learn about preventDefault and/or stopPropagation

Comment: @Andy I understand this is not a good practice and I am suffering with this. I just want to know, for example is there a way to pass the preventDefault() to the <a> parent? with the <a> direct parent it works.

Comment: @epascarello I am very excited to receive help from you and the other members of this community. I know it's not the best practice, but maybe for this question the solution is to use preventDefault, but I don't know how to do it for the <a> parent.

Comment: You do it in the click event of the button. Has nothing to do with the parent.

Comment: @epascarello I use the preventDefault in the button function, but this only works for the direct parent of the button, which is a <a> this does not prevent navigation of the parent <a>.

Comment: @yavgz as per @epascarello has commented, all browsers rectify the invalid code, whereby `<a><a></a></a>` does not exist because it renders as `<a></a><a></a>`. Therefore, the anchor tags are not parent/child of one another. They are instead siblings. There is a buttload of articles on Google explaining why your code is invalid. Please do some research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **dirty** solution.

Loop through all of the buttons wrapped by an anchor and replace the anchor tag with the button with a new class added. And add a click handler to the body and look for clicks on the element with that class.

And hide the extra top most anchor via CSS.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.className.indexOf("btnClick") > -1) {
    console.log("clicked")
  }
});

let linkBTNs = document.querySelectorAll("a > button");

linkBTNs.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.className = "btnClick";
  btn.parentNode.replaceWith(btn)
});
```

```css
.btnClick {
  color: red;
}

html,body{height:100%;}
#mainLink{display:none}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" id="mainLink">
   go to google
    <a href="www.wikipedia.com" id="secondaryLink">
        go to wikipedia
        <button>click</button>
    </a>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onclick="clickedButton(event)">click</button>


<script>
clickedButton = function(e){
console.log("click");
[...] Any code you want
e.preventDefault();
</script>
```

"*The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur. For example, this can be useful when: Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form. Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL*" - [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)